# Perl: Splitting a hash into several based on its keys?

Tags: regex, perl, hashtable

Let's say that I have a hashref whose `Data::Dumper` output looks like this:

```
    $VAR1 = {
        foo_0 => 'foo_zero',
        foo_1 => 'foo_one',
        bar_0 => 'bar_zero',
        bar_1 => 'bar_one'
    }
```

I would like to split this hash into two based on its keys as shown below but I don't know how to do this:

```
    $VAR1 = {
        foo_0 => 'foo_zero',
        foo_1 => 'foo_one'
    },
    $VAR2 = {
        bar_0 => 'bar_zero',
        bar_1 => 'bar_one'
    }
```

The keys of the first hash match `/foo_[\d]/` while those of the second hash match `/bar_[\d]/`.
If you could kindly tell me how to do this (or hint me some search keywords) I would appreciate it.

Regards,
Christopher Smith

Comment: for perl var to be a hash, doesn't it have to start with %?  I'm not sure if hashref means something different..

Comment: A hashref indeed has a $ prefix. Also please mind that the code block is a copy&paste of the result of `print Dumper($myhashref);` using `Data::Dumper`.

Comment: @ThunderRabbit: OP has a hashref, not a hash. They are different. A hashref is a reference to a hash and references are a kind of *scalars*. More you can find on the [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) page.

Comment: Thank you Art!   I'll stop tweaking my answer and let you take over.. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other solutions posted so far work, but are quick and dirty. They need to be changed when the input patterns change, and assume only two patterns. This generalised solution does not suffer from that: it needs no change, and it takes any number of patterns.

```
sub classify_hashref {
    my ($href, %p) = @_;
    my $r;
    for my $hkey (keys %{ $href }) {
        for my $pkey (keys %p) {
            $r->{$pkey}{$hkey} = $href->{$hkey}
                if $hkey =~ $p{$pkey};
        }
    }
    return $r;
}

my $h = {
    foo_0 => 'foo_zero',
    foo_1 => 'foo_one',
    bar_0 => 'bar_zero',
    bar_1 => 'bar_one'
};
classify_hashref($h, foo_like => qr/^foo_/, looks_like_bar => qr/^bar_/);
# {
#     looks_like_bar => {
#         bar_0 => 'bar_zero',
#         bar_1 => 'bar_one'
#     },
#     foo_like => {
#         foo_0 => 'foo_zero',
#         foo_1 => 'foo_one'
#     }
# }
```

Comment: Neat! This does indeed what I've expected, and I can even reuse this function within all over my project. Thank you very much for your solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that your hash reference is `$foo_ref`. You didn't state what would happen if your hash key is neither a `foo` or a `bar`. You could do one of three things:

- You have to hash references. One of `foo` keys and one of all other keys.
- You throw out keys that are neither `foo` keys or `bar` keys. (This is what I did).
- You have a third hash which stores all non-foo and non-bar keys.

The program below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use Data::Dumper;

my $foo_re = qr/^foo_/;
my $bar_re = qr/^bar_/;

my $foo_ref = {
    foo_0 => "foo_zero",
    foo_1 => "foo_one",
    bar_0 => "bar_zero",
    bar_1 => "bar_one",
};

my $bar_ref = {};
foreach my $key (keys %{$foo_ref}) {
    if (not $key =~ $foo_re) {

    # Remove if clause to store all non-foo keys in $bar_re
    $bar_ref->{$key} = $foo_ref->{$key} if $key =~ $bar_re;
    delete $foo_ref->{$key}
    }
}

say Dumper $foo_ref;
say Dumper $bar_ref;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that all your hash keys has one of the 2 provided patterns. If not, then you should specify more exactly what you have and what you expect.
If you want to process the output of the *dump*, I'm also assuming it has a correct format suitable for `eval`. Just put your output inside `q(` and  `)`:

```
# ...

my $VAR1;

eval q(
    $VAR1 = {
        foo_0 => 'foo_zero',
        foo_1 => 'foo_one',
        bar_0 => 'bar_zero',
        bar_1 => 'bar_one'
    }
);

my $h1 = {};
my $h2 = {};

for my $k ( keys %{$VAR1} ) {
    if ( $k =~ /foo_\d/  ) {
        $h1->{$k} = $VAR1->{$k};
        next;
    }

    $h2->{$k} = $VAR1->{$k};  # the remaining  /bar_\d/ case
}

# use your new $h1 and $h2 hasrefs
# ...
```

You will get 2 new hasrefs `$h1` and `$h2`.
If you have other cases besides these 2, you shoul put everyone inside an `if`, not only the first.
This is not a complete script, just a snippet.